# Creating a Custom Jump To Next Character Occurence Shortcut in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to create a keyboard shortcut in VS Code that will jump to the next occurrence of the period character "." (or any character) in VS Code? I'm looking for functionality similar to the cursorEnd or jumpToBracket commands instead of the Find command.

I tried adding a custom key bind through Keybindings.json but the available commands don't seem to have the option for this.
There is the "editor.action.jumpToBracket" command and the various "cursor..." commands which have similar functionality to what I'm looking for, so I am thinking the functionality would be doable.

I did come across the [jump and select](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.jump-and-select) extension which makes me think it would be more effort that it's worth but I thought I would inquire here just in case there is an easy way to implement this behavior.

I may be missing something obvious but after looking around and searching for similar answers I haven't found much that looks like what I'm wanting, so if anybody knows how to do this or can point me in the direction to find out how that would be great.

Comment: You could use the Find (CTRL + F), enter the character(s) you want to find, and the use F3 to go to the next one. `F3` would be your shortcut in this case - obviously though the find dialog would be open, and it would highlight all occurences.

Comment: @TimothyG. That is my usual go to and it works well enough, but as you say the dialog would be open and occurrences highlighted so I was a curious if there was a *cleaner* way to do it.  However, if it means digging through and editing and creating a bunch of files I'm not familiar with I'll use the extension I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Here is another, simpler way using a different extension that I wrote: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).  I also wrote the `Jump and Select` extension that you mentioned.

I'll show three keybindings for three different workflows.

1. Jump to next occurrence of character at cursor

```json
{
  "key": "alt+j",                 // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {

    // select character to left of cursor
    "preCommands": ["cancelSelection", "cursorLeftSelect"],
    "restrictFind": "nextMoveCursor"
  }

  // "when": ""  // to restrict to specific languages
}
```

2. Jump to next occurrence of selection:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+j",                 // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "restrictFind": "nextSelect"   // this is slightly different
  }

  // "when": ""  // to restrict to specific languages
}
```

3. Open an input box for which character or characters to jump to:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+j",                 // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "preCommands": ["cancelSelection", "cursorLeftSelect"],
    
    "find": "${getInput}",              // add this
    // "isRegex": true,                 // if you want the input treated as aregex
    "restrictFind": "nextMoveCursor"
  }

  // "when": ""  // to restrict to specific languages
}
```

With (3) you do have to keep typing the next characters to jump to - but they can be anything, even a regex you keeping pasting into the input.

Demo of (1):

[image: demo of jump to next occurrence of character at cursor]

Demo of (2) with a selection:

[image: demo of jumping to next selection]

Demo of (3) - pasting a regex into the input box:

[image: demo of pasting a regex into an input box to jump to]

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out, looks like that'll do what I'm looking for. Also, would you say creating custom commands like these is easy enough to get into and worthwhile if it's purely to improve and customize my own experience?